# connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

I am trying to run a website sent to me but after doing so this error appeared

> connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "4X.XXX.XX.XXX", user "userXXX", database "dbXXX", SSL off in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmastool\index.php on line 37

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392482/postgres-pg-hba-conf) that says that I just need to add an entry in the `pg_hba.conf` file for that particular user.

This is my `pg_hba.conf` file.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
local dbXXX userXXX md5
host    dbXXX  userXXX  XX.XXX.XXX.XXX           md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

but after doing so, the error still persists. I restarted my XAMPP server several times but nothing changes.

What do I need to change in `pg_hba.conf`?

Answer (score 439, accepted):

Add or edit the following line in your `postgresql.conf` :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Add the following line as the first line of `pg_hba.conf`. It allows access to all databases for all users with an encrypted password:

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 scram-sha-256
```

Restart Postgresql after adding this with `service postgresql restart` or the equivalent command for your setup. For brew, `brew services restart postgresql`

Edit: The authentication method was updated from `md5` to `scram-sha-256` because "the MD5 hash algorithm is nowadays no longer considered secure against determined attacks." Please note that `scram-sha-256` "is the most secure of the currently provided methods, but it is not supported by older client libraries." Source: [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html)

Comment: Note that for this to work, [a password must have been set for the user](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/firstconnect.html): `sudo -u <username> psql postgres` , then `\password` at the resultant sql prompt will prompt for setting one.

Comment: If you want a little extra security limiting the connections to private domains (such as within an office, and not the rest of the Internet), you can change the first number to 10, 172 or 192 to match your network: for example 172.0.0.0/0 instead of 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: You also need to add a line with an address of `::0/0`, otherwise connections from IPv6 addresses will still be rejected.

Comment: I would add one other best practice when editing .conf files for any application, be sure to first make a backup copy ending with .bak or similar. Then in the edited file sandwich your edits in comment lines to note begin and end of your changes as well as a comment line for the purpose and who to contact. This will save you much trouble later. Be sure to make notes of what was changed and in what files, where, and put those notes in a consistent place that is related and locatable.

Comment: I had to add a firewall rule before the above worked, run the following in an elevated powershell window.  New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow

Comment: That's no so smart - now any IP can connect - you might want to limit it to your internal network addresses. More precisely, to the narrowest range of your internal network addresses that need access.

Comment: You can also reload pg_hba.conf with `SELECT pg_reload_conf()`

Comment: @NateWanner Your example should read 172.0.0.0/8, otherwise it's no different than 0.0.0.0/0!

Comment: @not2savvy Thanks! Good catch.

Comment: Also make sure you've entered the right password. Otherwise you'll get the same error message even if your network configuration is right.

Comment: Or enable SSL in your framework. Example if using NestJS add 
`
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            ssl: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
            },
        }),
`

Answer (score 46):

This solution works for IPv4 / IPv6:

#### Edit pga_hba.conf File

Open up the `pga_hba.conf` file in your favourite editor:

```bash
[root@localhost ~]#  nano /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

#### Append To pga_hba.conf File

Append the following lines to the end of the `pga_hba.conf` file:

```bash
host all all      ::1/128      md5
host all postgres 127.0.0.1/32 md5
```

Quit and save the editor of your preference.

#### Restart Service

Restart the `postgresql` service with the following command:

```bash
[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Comment: only worked when I used `::0/0`

Comment: My path was `/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf` on Ubuntu 20.

Comment: For me it worked with ::0/0 only.

Comment: ::0/0 works for connections not coming from localhost. ::1/128 is just for localhost
It is better to connect remotely using SSH or something secure, not directly to the database, at least if you want a secured system, as defined by PCI.

Comment: You can use `pg_ctl reload` to reload the config without downtime. At least you can in the Red Hat version of Postgres that I was using. It may differ across different implementations.

Answer (score 30):

The way I solved this was:

Added the line as below in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
hostnossl    all          all            0.0.0.0/0  trust
```

and this was modified in `postgresql.conf`, as shown:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I had this instance running on a *Centos 7.3* and *Postgres 9.5* in a VM in *Azure*, given this was a POC (proof of concept) you won't want to connect without SSL in your actual prod environment.

To connect to the instance I was using *pgAdmin 4* on macOS *Sierra*.

Comment: Not only SSL... on anything that is not a proof of concept and is network acessible, you would not *trust* connections, you would require some *authentication*.

Answer (score 19):

Instructions for Debian users.

Login as posgres user:

```
$ sudo su - postgres
```

Get the location of pg_hba.conf by quering the database:

```
$ psql -c "SHOW hba_file;"

              hba_file               
-------------------------------------
/etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)
```

Open pg_hba.conf:

```
nano /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Add configuration where it says "Put your actual configuration here":

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Logout to your user:

```
$ exit
logout
```

Restart your postgres server for changes to take effect:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Answer (score 16):

Fresh Postgres 9.5 install, Ubuntu.

The key was the *local* connection type, since psql uses domain socket connection.

pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
local all all md5
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Answer (score 13):

1. Add the following line in the bottom of `pg_hba.conf`:

   `hostnossl    all          all            0.0.0.0/0  md5`
2. Add/modify the line in `postgresql.conf`:

   `listen_addresses = '*'`
3. MAKE SURE THAT the user that is connecting has a password: (Example connect user named `postgres`)

   a. Run the following `psql` command with the `postgres` user account:

   `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`

   b. Set the password:

   `# \password postgres`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This below worked for me: (pg_hba.conf)

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only     
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

> trust
>
> Allow the connection unconditionally. This method allows anyone that
>   can connect to the PostgreSQL database server to login as any
>   PostgreSQL user they wish, without the need for a password or any
>   other authentication.
>
> md5
>
> Require the client to supply a double-MD5-hashed password for
>   authentication.

refer for more [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/serverguide/postgresql.html)

Answer (score 9):

In my case I ran into this where I didn't have access to edit any conf files on the server (.NET connecting to a managed db on DigitalOcean)  so the other answers weren't an option.

The host provided me a `postgresql://` connection URL which had a `?sslmode=` option on the end.  I got the exact same error until I added `"SSL Mode=Prefer;Trust Server Certificate=true;"` to my translated [.NET connectionString](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#security-and-encryption).

That may not be the optimal solution for me or for you, but I wanted to point out it's possible that this is an issue with the connection string rather than the server config.

Comment: I had same issue.  When connecting with Npgsql, if database expects SSL connection and you omit it from connection string, then you get a bizarre pg_hfa.conf error.

Comment: I had the same issue with Azure's new "flexible server" while trying to connect with psql. Adding `--set=sslmode=require` to the command fixed it.

Comment: Same with me. Was connecting AWS DMS to a hosted Postgres (on Aptible). Setting `sslmode=required` eliminated the `pg_hba.conf` error.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error when I tried to connect to a local database using an SSH tunnel. I solved it by changing the host name from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had to add the exact line as suggested by the error information. Cannot bypass it by adding "all" users with all IPs as rule. Now it is like:

PosgreSQL 10.5 on CentOS 7.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32                    md5
host    <db_name>       postgres        <my_client_machine_ip>/32       md5
```

Answer (score 4):

Find the correct configuration file:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -t -P format=unaligned -c 'show hba_file';"
```

Add the following at the end of file:

```
local all all peer
```

Then restart your PostgreSQL application:

```
/bin/systemctl restart postgresql*.service
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the link https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/noalyss/administration/configure-pgadmin/.

For PgAdmin 4 on Windows. I added these lines below

pg_hba.config:

```
host all all all md5
```

and modify postgresql.config:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```