# docker and postgres: using password_file leads to no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm aware of the following solution for the `no pg_hba.conf entry for host` error: [connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)

But I wonder why this error happens when using Postgres environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE` in Docker, and not when setting the password directly with an environment variable such as `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`.

Here are the most useful bits of code. If you want to see a complete example, please take a look at [this repository](https://github.com/Pawamoy/docker-postgres-password-file).

This version will trigger the error:

```
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:10
    volumes:
      - ./pass/db/db_pass:/run/secrets/db_pass:ro
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db_pass
```

While this version will work fine:

```
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:10
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=db_password
```

The `./pass/db/db_pass` file contains exactly the same password: `db_password`.

Basically, the only thing that changes between the two configuration is that setting the password for the database container is 1) done with an environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` and 2) done reading the file pointed by `POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE`, file which is bind-mounted inside the container as read-only.

If we look at the Postgres' entrypoint, `POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE` is used to fill `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/10/docker-entrypoint.sh#L8-L24.

```
# usage: file_env VAR [DEFAULT]
#    ie: file_env 'XYZ_DB_PASSWORD' 'example'
# (will allow for "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD_FILE" to fill in the value of
#  "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD" from a file, especially for Docker's secrets feature)
file_env() {
    local var="$1"
    local fileVar="${var}_FILE"
    local def="${2:-}"
    if [ "${!var:-}" ] && [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
        echo >&2 "error: both $var and $fileVar are set (but are exclusive)"
        exit 1
    fi
    local val="$def"
    if [ "${!var:-}" ]; then
        val="${!var}"
    elif [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
        val="$(< "${!fileVar}")"
    fi
    export "$var"="$val"
    unset "$fileVar"
}
```

I don't get why then Postgres throws this `no pg_hba.conf entry for host` error if the database has been correctly created with the given password.

Looking at the entry point, the configuration should be the exact same, but I verified both with the command `docker-compose -f no-file.yml run --rm database /bin/bash -c 'cat $PGDATA/pg_hba.conf'` and the line `host all all all md5` does not appear in the configuration using `POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE`.

Why does the default configuration changes when we make use of the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE` variable, and how to fix this elegantly? Do I have to provide a custom Postgres configuration file as described in https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/, section "Database configuration"?

Comment: Actually I opened an issue in the repository: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/438

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a permission issue.

```
database_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 19: /run/secrets/db_pass: Permission denied
```

My password file had `-rw-------` permissions. Since the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script sets the `-e` option, it was exiting early, right after this error, preventing to append the `host all all all md5` line to `pg_hba.conf`.

I added `r` for group and others, as well as `r-x` for group and others on its parent directory. That fixed the issue.