# PostGIS in docker file FATAL no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql, postgis, docker

I have a docker-compose.yml file with two image (Postgres extended PostGIS and pgadmin4):

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  postgis:
    image: postgis/postgis:15-3.3
    container_name: postgis_container
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - 5432
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=dem
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS=postgis,hstore,postgis_topology,postgis_raster,pgrouting
    volumes:
      - postgis-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        # postgis_logs:/var/lib/postgresql/logs

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - postgis


volumes:
  postgis-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

Everything works perfectly but I can't seem to connect the docker container with the QGIS application:

[image]

The error message:

[image]

I have searched the net for different solutions trying for several days but I am stuck on all attempts. I understand that you have to edit the file pg_hba.conf in var/lib/data/pg_hba.conf (in the container):

note: I have tried and retried all the modification solutions on the net such as those proposed by: [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host) but to no avail

```
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#
# Refer to the "Client Authentication" section in the PostgreSQL
# documentation for a complete description of this file.  A short
# synopsis follows.
#
# This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# are authenticated, which PostgreSQL user names they can use, which
# databases they can access.  Records take one of these forms:
#
# local         DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host          DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl     DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostgssenc    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnogssenc  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#
# (The uppercase items must be replaced by actual values.)
#
# The first field is the connection type:
# - "local" is a Unix-domain socket
# - "host" is a TCP/IP socket (encrypted or not)
# - "hostssl" is a TCP/IP socket that is SSL-encrypted
# - "hostnossl" is a TCP/IP socket that is not SSL-encrypted
# - "hostgssenc" is a TCP/IP socket that is GSSAPI-encrypted
# - "hostnogssenc" is a TCP/IP socket that is not GSSAPI-encrypted
#
# DATABASE can be "all", "sameuser", "samerole", "replication", a
# database name, or a comma-separated list thereof. The "all"
# keyword does not match "replication". Access to replication
# must be enabled in a separate record (see example below).
#
# USER can be "all", a user name, a group name prefixed with "+", or a
# comma-separated list thereof.  In both the DATABASE and USER fields
# you can also write a file name prefixed with "@" to include names
# from a separate file.
#
# ADDRESS specifies the set of hosts the record matches.  It can be a
# host name, or it is made up of an IP address and a CIDR mask that is
# an integer (between 0 and 32 (IPv4) or 128 (IPv6) inclusive) that
# specifies the number of significant bits in the mask.  A host name
# that starts with a dot (.) matches a suffix of the actual host name.
# Alternatively, you can write an IP address and netmask in separate
# columns to specify the set of hosts.  Instead of a CIDR-address, you
# can write "samehost" to match any of the server's own IP addresses,
# or "samenet" to match any address in any subnet that the server is
# directly connected to.
#
# METHOD can be "trust", "reject", "md5", "password", "scram-sha-256",
# "gss", "sspi", "ident", "peer", "pam", "ldap", "radius" or "cert".
# Note that "password" sends passwords in clear text; "md5" or
# "scram-sha-256" are preferred since they send encrypted passwords.
#
# OPTIONS are a set of options for the authentication in the format
# NAME=VALUE.  The available options depend on the different
# authentication methods -- refer to the "Client Authentication"
# section in the documentation for a list of which options are
# available for which authentication methods.
#
# Database and user names containing spaces, commas, quotes and other
# special characters must be quoted.  Quoting one of the keywords
# "all", "sameuser", "samerole" or "replication" makes the name lose
# its special character, and just match a database or username with
# that name.
#
# This file is read on server startup and when the server receives a
# SIGHUP signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have to
# SIGHUP the server for the changes to take effect, run "pg_ctl reload",
# or execute "SELECT pg_reload_conf()".
#
# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.

# CAUTION: Configuring the system for local "trust" authentication
# allows any local user to connect as any PostgreSQL user, including
# the database superuser.  If you do not trust all your local users,
# use another authentication method.


# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all scram-sha-256
```

---

UPDATED

---

with the Docker comand I find th IP addrss of the container with postgis:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' postgis_container
'172.20.0.2'
```

Try again in QGIS:

[image]

but different error:

[image]

Comment: The error message in your screenshot disagrees with the one in your title.

Comment: Where is QGIS running?

Comment: What (if anything) shows up in the log for docker container 'postgis' when this error occurs?

Comment: QGIS run on Windows in my local machine outside the container

Comment: On docker on windows, if you start a container `ports: "5432:5432"` but 5432 is already in use on the docker host machine, then it just fails to map the port from the host, but proceeds with the rest of the startup anyway, which means your attempts to connect to localhost:5432 would then be going to some other PostgreSQL server which was already listening on your system (either running directly on Windows, or with a mapping from 5432 to a container).

Comment: Your second attempt is just weird.  the error clearly says it is trying to connect to some nonstandard port (50385) in two different places, while the config says to use 5432.

Comment: Thanks. In the second attempt the port is different because i tried (a lot) different setup changing, for example, the port. With pgadim or cloudbeaver I can connect to my postgres db but not from QGIS. I really not understand the reason

Comment: So what error do you get when using the correct port with the 172.20.0.2 IP address?  The error message from when you used the wrong port is not informative.

Comment: It's password authentication error